# Getting Devise AJAX sign in working with confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

We're trying to extend Devise (3.1.1) signin/signup methods to handle AJAX requests, but are getting stuck with the confirmable logic. Normally, if a user signs in to Devise before confirming their account, they'll get redirected to the login screen with the flash message: *"You have to confirm your account before continuing."* We can't figure out where Devise is checking for confirmation and making the decision to redirect.

Here's our extended **sessions_controller** code. It works fine for successful and failed login attempts:

```
  # CUSTOM (Mix of actual devise controller method and ajax customization from http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/):
  def create
    # (NOTE: If user is not confirmed, execution will never get this far...)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do 
        # Copied from original create method:
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
        set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      end                       
      format.js  do
        # Derived from Natasha AJAX recipe:
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        return render :json => {:success => true, :token => form_authenticity_token() }, content_type: "application/json" # Need to explicitely set content type to JSON, otherwise it gets set as application/javascript and success handler never gets hit.
      end          
    end

  end

  def failure
    return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end
```

The problem is, if a user is unconfirmed, the `create` method never gets hit. The redirection happens somewhere before, which means we can't handle it in a JS friendly manner. But looking through the source I can't find any before filter that does a confirmable check. Where is the confirmable check happening and how can we intercept it?

Comment: what u want actually? and I recommend u to go through this http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable

Comment: You've actually done very well getting the code sorted to handle JSON

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's happening is that the `sign_in` method is breaking you out of the normal flow by throwing a warden error, which will call the failure app.

If you look at the definition of `sign_in` in `lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb`, you'll see that in a normal flow where you're signing in a user for the first time, you wind up calling

`warden.set_user(resource, options.merge!(:scope => scope)`

`warden` is a reference to a `Warden::Proxy` object, and if you look at what `set_user` does (you can see that at [`warden/lib/warden/proxy.rb:157-182`](https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L157)), you'll see that after serializing the user into the session it runs any `after_set_user` callbacks.

Devise defines a bunch of these in `lib/devise/hooks/`, and the particular one we're interested is in `lib/devise/hooks/activatable.rb`:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |record, warden, options|
  if record && record.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) && !record.active_for_authentication?
    scope = options[:scope]
    warden.logout(scope)
    throw :warden, :scope => scope, :message => record.inactive_message
  end
end
```

As you can see, if the record is not `active_for_authentication?`, then we `throw`. This is what is happening in your case -- `active_for_authentication?` returns false for a `confirmable` resource that is not yet confirmed (see [`lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:121-127`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L121)).

And when we `throw :warden`, we end up calling the devise `failure_app`. So that's what's happening, and why you're breaking out of the normal control flow for your controller.

(Actually the above is talking about the normal sessions controller flow. I think your `js` block is actually redundant -- calling `warden.authenticate!` will set the user as well, so I think you're throwing before you even get to `sign_in`.)

To answer your *second* question, one possible way of handling this is to create your own failure app. By default devise sets warden's `failure_app` to `Devise::Delegator`, which allows you to specify different failure apps for different devise models, but defaults to `Devise::FailureApp` if nothing has been configured. You could either customize the existing failure app, replace it with your own failure app by configuring warden, or you could customize the delegator to use the default failure app for html requests and delegate to a different failure app for json.

Comment: @gregates- Really appreciate the in-depth answer, but what you describe doesn't seem to be the case. If I try to raise an artificial error in the very first line of the `create` method, it never gets hit, so I know that Devise is doing the check before my code ever gets a chance to call sign_in/warden.authenticate or anything else. Any ideas?

Comment: unfortunately not really -- I've described where devise checks whether the user is confirmed on sign in, so if something is short-circuiting your controller with that check I don't believe it's default devise.

Comment: @gregates- We just figured out what was going on. This is the right answer, but we had some before_filters in the ApplicationController that were `checking user_signed_in?` etc, and that was causing Warden to throw before our SessionController even got hit- short-circuiting the controller logic, like you said. Implementing a custom FailureApp did the trick- I describe our solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19879806/165673. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could point you in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 3):

I met same problem before. Actually it can be solved very simply.

Go to `config/initializers/devise.rb`, find the following line

```
# ==> Configuration for :confirmable
# A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
# confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
# able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
# access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
# the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 0.days
```

Activate the last line and set the period as what you like, say `7.days`

This period is a grace period, once set, you can expect

1. User can be signed in automatically after signing up, no more redirection to confirmation page.
2. Within this period, unconfirmed user can be remembered, and signed in without problem.
3. After the period expired, unconfirmed user will be redirect to confirmation page and must confirm password before continuing.

With `:confirmable` enabled, I'm afraid the grace period is the most user friendly. If you are even not satisfied with that, there is little points to use `:confirmable` :)

#### Side notes about JSON response

I just noticed you used JSON response when I read Rich Peck's comment. I would suggest you not to use JSON response, instead, a simpler approach to use an Ajax/Plain JS form as login form, and expect Devise to do normal page redirect. The reason is there would be too much resources to update if using JSON response, for example, csrf_token, cookie, existing authorization etc. See my other answer about similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538974/1721198

Comment: Thanks, it's a good thought but using the grace period really isn't what I'm after because I *don't* want the user to be able to log in before they're confirmed, I just want to be able to handle it gracefully when making AJAX calls. And per your side note about JSON response, I hear you and agree that logging in without a post back is generally impractical. However, we have a complex lazy-registration scenario where live form data needs to be submitted only after a successful login- we do that by logging in via AJAX and passing a new token back, which then triggers a form submit.

Comment: @Yarin, thanks for the response. I misunderstood your question in my answer. Now I understand it but don't have enough time to dig it at this moment :) However, at first glance, it seems your code is a bit strange that you defined respond logic at first and authentication later. I guess that may be the reason you claim the authenticate code never get hit.

Answer (score 3):

@gregates gets credit for figuring this out, but I wanted to show how I actually got this working:

The problem was you can't check for or intercept an unconfirmed user at the controller level because it gets checked at the model level with `active_for_authentication?`, and then gets handled by Warden's failure app immediately. So any reference to `current_user` will short-circuit whatever controller logic you've got going on. The solution is to introduce your own custom FailureApp, and handle things as you see fit. In our case, that meant raising a special error for AJAX auth errors. Here's how we did it:

First, create a custom failure app, as described here:
[How To: Redirect to a specific page when the user can not be authenticated · plataformatec/devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated)

**lib/custom_failure.rb:**

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  def respond

    # We override Devise's handling to throw our own custom errors on AJAX auth failures,
    # because Devise provides no easy way to deal with them:

    if request.xhr? && warden_message == :unconfirmed
      raise MyCustomErrors::AjaxAuthError.new("Confirmation required. Check your inbox.")
    end

    # Original code:

    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    elsif warden_options[:recall]
      recall
    else
      redirect
    end
  end

end
```

And then tell Warden to use the custom failure app:

**config/initializers/devise.rb:**

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

And then you just handle your custom error however you like. In our case, we had our ErrorController return a 401 JSON response.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you have a gist detailing your MyCustomErrors::AjaxAuthError class?

Comment: @marflar - It's just an empty extension of RuntimeError that we define in our app's lib directory: `class AjaxAuthError < RuntimeError; end`. It doesn't *do* anything, it just allows us to look for and handle that particular error type in our app's universal `ErrorsController` class (For details on implementing an ErrorsController see this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/53-handling-exceptions-revised))

Answer (score 1):

To add to @gregates answer, try overriding the method `active_for_authentication?` in your User(resource) model like this:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  true
end
```

If you are able to login, then the issue has to be with your sessions controller. Make sure you havent missed anything obvious like specfying the route to your new sessions controller

Comment: Nice general debugging tip.