# Authentication with Devise, Rails using backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, devise

I am new to backbone and been trying to pull off an authentication but in vain. Please help over here;

My view looks like this;

```
mama.Views.UserSessionsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['user_sessions/index'],
  render: function() {      
    this.$el.html( this.template );
    return this;
  },
  events: {
            "click #sign_in_button": "signIn"
        },  

  signIn: function(event) {
    var userSession = new Skymama.Models.UserSession;
    userSession.set({email: $('#email_address').val(), password: $('#password').val()});
    userSession.save({
        success: function(model, response) {
           alert("response"); 
        },

        error: function(model, response){
            alert("response");
        }
    });
  }

});
```

However, i get this response `401 Unauthorized` for an authorised error. How can i handle these response, log in the client and redirect them. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you finally expect a redirect, don't use Backbone model because JSON response won't get you redirected.

Instead, within this Backbone view, display traditional Devise form and send HTML request.

Comment: That's just basic Devise things. You just moved the html into this view.

Comment: i want to handle this in a single page app working through a rails API. I am comfortable with normal devise.

Comment: It may not be that easy as you supposed. The first thing is the authentication token which is not hard. And then, if you have any logic based on current_user's attributes say a role, they must be all updated. Things will get complicated as app evolves. So I suggest you to implement normal redirect at first and consider this feature the last. See my other similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414393/ember-js-session-cookie-based-authentication-with-rails-and-devise/19538974#19538974

Comment: Awesome!! i was just getting to that point of giving up the whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need a RESTful way to login from Backbone to Rails (Devise).

> Tutorial 1: http://joshhuckabee.com/integrating-devise-backbonejs
>
> Tutorial 2: http://chasseurmic.github.io/chasseurmic/blog/2013/02/13/restful-api-authentication/

Prepare the RESTful config/controller. After, using a POST call you can authenticate with Rails.